# Powershell variable is lost

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-cmdlet

My code:

```
    Write-Output "mytest" 
    $var1="defucntion"  
    $var1  
    Get-ChildItem variable:var*  
    Remove-Variable $var1  
    Get-ChildItem Variable:
```

I entered the code into Visual Studio Code. But got an error like this:

```
Remove-Variable : 找不到名为“defucntion”的变量。
所在位置 C:\Users\Administrator\mine\Ps1 1\test1.ps1:5 字符: 1
+ Remove-Variable $var1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (defucntion:String) 
[RemoveVariable], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveVariableCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be passing through name reference as a string to Remove-Variable

`Remove-Variable "var1"`

```
SYNTAX
    Remove-Variable [-Name] <string[]>
```

In your case you are passing though a variable value, e.g. "defucntion", but variable with name "defucntion" doesn't exist.

p.s. You can check help for functions by using Get-Help to identify parameter types